# PHP Not running after Permalink structure change (WORDPRESS)

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

My site is currently showing PHP code only and it doesnt seem to execute php
https://mycountrycafe.com/

I had to change the permalink structure to the postname for SEO purposes and after the change it does not show the content. It displays the php code.

Using godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not permalink problem.
Try to rename plugins folder and load homepage. 
If it solves your problem, rename plugins folder back and rename plugin by plugin to find the culprit

Comment: Looks like the site is loading, what is the problem.

Comment: i had to delete htaccess then restored the permalink_structure to default via phpmyadmin

Comment: so the site is back up

Comment: Can you share me .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Please,First of all must be stop your website because your config file now is appear for everyone and  sure for that your Apache is working well.